# ...verb+ところあったのか

Tags: grammar

I've come across this statement in a manga recently:

> 今までの話で笑うトコあったのか俺マジ判んないんだけど？

The part I am having trouble with is "今までの話で笑うトコあったのか".
I'm familiar with plain present verb + ところだ/です = "be about to [verb]". But the use of ある vs です is throwing me. Also I think か in this case has to do with an embedded question, but I do see an interrogative. If some one has a translation for this and could possibly break it down for me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 6):

ところ in this sentence means "part". 笑うトコあったのか means "Is there a part which we laugh at."

ところ means "part, place". For example, この辺に走る(走れる)所あったっけ? (Is there a place around here where I can run?).

Comment: So it was more literal than grammatical, maybe that's why they put トコ in katakana. Seems so obvious now. Thank you very much.